# Get _POST from Select element in Form

Tags: form, php, post

I'm  trying to get the _POST data for my form in a plugin, and for whatever reason am unable to get the selected option from a select tag:

```
 <form class="parseResults" action="actions/MyPlugin/myFunctionAjax" method="post" name="submitResults">
    <select name="submission">
        <option value="view">View</option>
        <option value="submit">Submit</option>
    </select>
    <textarea rows="9" cols="80" name="content"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

And then in my plugin, I can get the textarea form content like:

```
    $formContent = craft()->request->getPost('content');
```

But when I try to get the selected option from the #submission select, nothing returns

```
    $submissionType = craft()->request->getPost('submission');
```

What am I missing or doing wrong in order to get the selected option?

Comment: In CraftCMS, is there a folder named 'actions'?  I was thinking that the requirement is to have the folder named 'plugins'?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Form elements need to have a name attribute.

```
<select name="submission" id="submission">
<option value="view">View</option>
<option value="submit">Submit</option>
</select>

<textarea name="content" rows="9" cols="80" id="content"></textarea>
```

That should do the trick!